# Magento calling my namespace block from Mage namespace

Tags: magento, module, namespaces, block

I've been at this for several hours now. Magento keeps trying to call my block from the Mage namespace instead of my own.

Error:
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Newcart_Block_Adminhtml_Igrid' in /Library/WebServer/Documents/magento/app/Mage.php:594

I've looked everywhere trying to find the problem. I know it reaches my layout and that the handle works:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout version="0.1.0">

      <images_adminhtml_index_index>
           <reference name="content">
                  <block type="newcart/adminhtml_igrid"  name="adminblock" />
           </reference>
      </images_adminhtml_index_index>
</layout>
```

However my block (actually, a grid container) will not be called from the proper namespace:

app/code/local/[Namespace]/Newcart/Block/Adminhtml/Igrid.php

```
class [Namespace]_Newcart_Block_Adminhtml_Igrid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {

     $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_imagegrid';
     $this->_blockGroup = 'newcart';
     $this->_headerText = 'Images';
     $this->_addButtonLabel = 'Add an Image';

     parent::__construct();
     }

     protected function _prepareLayout()
     {
         //Mage::log($this->createBlock( $this->_blockGroup.'/' . $this->_controller . '_grid',
         //   $this->_controller . '.grid'), null, ‘layout.log’ );
        $this->setChild( 'grid',
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock( $this->_blockGroup.'/' . $this->_controller . '_grid',
            $this->_controller . '.grid')->setSaveParametersInSession(true) );
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
     }
}
```

Note: Imagegrid is a file in the same dir. I tried '$this->_controller = 'adminhtml_igrid';', 
But, it did nothing to resolve the issue.

Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

  <config>
     <modules>
        <[namespace]_Newcart>
          <version>0.1.0</version>
        </[namespace]_Newcart>
     </modules>
     <admin>
        <routers>
            <images>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>[namespace]_Newcart</module>
                    <frontName>imageadmin</frontName>
                </args>
            </images>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <images>
                    <file>images.xml</file>
                </images>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <[namespace]_newcart>
                <class>[namespace]_Newcart_Block</class>
            </[namespace]_newcart>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <images>
                <class>[namespace]_Newcart_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>image_resource</resourceModel>
            </images>  
            <image_resource>
                <class>[namespace]_Newcart_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <imagemodel>
                        <table>nw_images</table>
                    </imagemodel>
                </entities>
            </image_resource>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

I have looked everywhere for a cause and don't know where else to look for an error. Please help!!!

Comment: Magento's trying to instantiate a block with the class alias "newcart/adminhtml_igrid".  Does your module's config.xml setup a base classname for "newcart" blocks?

Comment: Yes. However, it still refuses to call the namespace for the block. I've got several modules working with code very much similar to this, but I just can't get this one to work.

Comment: If your group name is [namespace]_newcart, then your block should reflect that (<block type="[namespace]_newcart/adminhtml_igrid" )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer (Thanks, ivantedja!)

It should be 'newcart', not '[namespace]_newcart' (in the blocks node, you don't need to specify the namespace)

Answer (score 0):

Just add the next code to config.xml of your module:

```
<config>
    ...
    <global>
        ...
        <blocks>
            <[namespace]_newcart>
                <class>[Namespace]_Newcart_Block</class>
            </[namespace]_newcart>
        </blocks>
        ...
    </global>
    ...
</config>
```

Comment: navoq_sms probably isn't the right groupname to be using here.

Comment: sure, it's a copy-paste from my module. i have changed the comment. thx.

Comment: Actually, I already had the block in the Config. Even changing the code to your format isn't fixing the problem.

Comment: Too lazy to answer. It should be <newcart> not <[namespace]_newcart>

Comment: Bingo. I took off the namespace except for the class in the config and it loaded the block! Too bad your too lazy to answer. I can't select a comment as an answer.